# What was the age of King David when he married Bath Sheva?

Tags: king-david, bath-sheva

What was the age of King David when he married Bath Sheva?
Is it possible to know it from the Bible or from Chazal?

I tried to find information about it, but unfortunately, I couldn't find it.

Comment: If shlomo her son was twelve when he became king that should give you some idea.

Comment: There are some opinions about when he became a king. One opinion says it was at 12 years old, but other opinions (if I'm not mistaken - Abarbanel) say he was older.

Comment: https://www.aish.com/jl/h/cc/48937102.html

Comment: Note that given that Shlomo was 12 when he became king and that there was a previous child that died at birth, we can estimate that he married Bassheva about three years before. Fifteen years before David died at the age of 70 would be at age 55.

Comment: According to this Hebrew Wiki page, King David was 47 at the time of the incident with Bat Sheva, but the footnote (5) acknowledges that other sources may differ on this. https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%95%D7%91%D7%AA_%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%A2#הקשר_ורקע

Answer (score 4):

So the sefer - סדר הדורות הקצר seems to say not like what most people suggested above. See image here:

[image]

According to this view he would appear to have married Bas Sheva aged 57 with Shlomo being born the year after when he was 58.

Indeed, the Gemara in [Sanhedrin 69b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.69b.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) notes that she bore Shlomo at the age of 8 which would appear to tally with the sefer's report.